# How to do line-clamp with a learn more button in vue3

Tags: html, css, vuejs3, tailwind-css, vite

I am using vue3 with vitejs in one of my projects and I have stumbled upon an issue. I have the following codes.

```
<div>
  <p class="line-clamp-4">Some really long text here...</p>
  <a id="read-more" href="readmore.html">Read more</a>
</div>
```

I am using tailwindcss here and I was able to clamp 4 lines. I have a list of these texts and not every one of them will have line clamp. So, I only want to show the read more button, when the line-clamp is applied. Now, how do I know the line-clamp is applying to this text and I have to show the readmore button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did to achieve this:

```html
@foreach($module->captions as $caption)
<div class="mt-1 relative">
    <div id="body-{{$caption->id}}" class="text-md leading-7 text-gray-700 font-normal whitespace-pre-line line-clamp-6">
        {{ $caption->body }}
    </div>
</div>

<div id="readMore-{{$caption->id}}" class="hidden flex justify-center absolute bottom-0 left-0 bg-white w-full rounded-b-lg">
    <p class="text-blue-600 cursor-pointer py-2"></p>
</div>
@endforeach
```

```js
<script>
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('line-clamp-6')

    Array.from(elements).forEach((element) => {
        let captionId = element.id.split('-')[1];

        let body = document.getElementById('body-' + captionId)

        let readMore = document.getElementById('readMore-' + captionId)

        if (element.clientHeight === 168) {
            readMore.firstElementChild.innerText = 'Read More'
            readMore.classList.remove('hidden')

            readMore.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
                if (body.classList.contains('line-clamp-6')) {
                    body.classList.remove('line-clamp-6')
                    readMore.firstElementChild.innerText = 'Read Less'
                } else {
                    body.classList.add('line-clamp-6')
                    readMore.firstElementChild.innerText = 'Read More'
                }
            })
        }
    })
</script>
```

In my case I'm using a foreach to loop through some data but you should still be able to customize this to your needs. Basically, I'm getting all the elements that have a class name of `line-clamp-6`. Then were looping through those elements to see if they have a clientHeight of 168. If so, they need the Read More link.

Keep in mind you might need to check for a different clientHeight.

Then I listen for a click on the read more link if `line-clamp-6` is present then we remove it else we add it.

Hopefully this helps you. I through this together in the last hour so there may be a better way to do it but this seems to work for me.